# How to set state after data fetch complete in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
arrayOfIds.forEach((id) => {
      firestore
        .collection("foos")
        .doc(id)
        .get()
        .then((foo) => {
          fooArray.push(foo.data());
        });
    });
console.log(fooArray);
// some output
this.setState({ foos: fooArray });
// but nothing passed to the state
```

When I console.log fooArray I can see all the data but cant assign it to the state

Comment: Firestore returns a Promise, which is being resolved after the setState is called. https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5

Comment: You will need to setState only after all the queries are complete, which means you wil need to change the structure of this code to use promises correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 for(let id of arrayOfIds) {
     let foo = await firestore
              .collection("foos")
              .doc(id)
              .get();
     fooArray.push(foo.data());
 }
 console.log(fooArray);
 this.setState({ foos: fooArray });
```

This would set the state with the correct data - you didnt await the Promise returned by firestore but with this it should work.

Comment: That actually still won't work because the forEach loop does not know to await the results of each iteration.  What you've written will log an empty array and not wait for each query to complete.

Comment: I use for-of loops instead of .forEach() when I have sequential async work for this reason.

Comment: You *can* also use Promise.all(arrayOfIds.map(...etc...) just to wait for the resulting array of promises to resolve.

Comment: @DougStevenson you're right, my bad. I will edit my answer.